# CrfSharp file not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012

when I try to run crfsharp, I get the following error at VS2012,

+err{"Could not find file 'C:\codeplex\POIParser\data\training\POIParser_corpus.train.tag'.":"C:\codeplex\POIParser\data\training\POIParser_corpus.train.tag"}    System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

where can I find this file "POIParser_corpus.train.tag" ? I have downloaded both source code and main program of crfsharp and running it in VS2012.
Also I want to ask you can I use the CRFsharp to extract aspects by using training templates?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run it ?
To train a CRF model, you need to prepare training corpus, template file at first and run CRFSharpConsole.exe with some parameters. CRFSharpConsole.exe will show usage, if you run it without any parameters.

Actually, I recommend you to download demo package from [DOWNLOADS] section in CRFSharp project web site(http://crfsharp.codeplex.com) at first, and then play with demo. In demo package, it will show you how to run CRFSharp in command line. For example, you can download Named entity recognized demo in English demo and run batch file to train a new model and test it.

For POIParser_corpus.train.tag you mentioned, it's the training corpus for Chinese POI inner-structure parser. You can also download it and run build_model.bat to train the model, and run test_model.bat to test it.